# Копирование и вставка текста в JavaScriipt

Tags: javascript, браузер

Доброго времени суток! Возник такой вопрос. Я где-то слышал, что в JavaScript якобы есть возможность при вставке текста на страницу определить, откуда именно он был скопирован (если он был скопировани из какой-то вкладки в том же браузере). То есть допустим у меня открыта страница с url http://first.ru, я копирую там некий текст, затем программно с помощью JS вставляю его в текстбокс на странице с url http://second.ru, и якобы при вставке этого текста я могу определить, что я его скопировал со страницы с url http://first.ru. Действительно ли такое возможно, или я ошибаюсь? И если да, то как? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Такое невозможно, только если Вы сами не оставите там эту информацию при обработке событий ClipboardEvent непосредственно  при самом копировании.

Comment: Сомневаюсь что даже ОС помнит источник. Не говоря о том, чтобы `JS` получил эту приватную информацию.

Comment: На самом деле,  мне не кажется это таким уже не возможным. Как минимум, информация о источнике присутствует в буфере обмена. Можно это проверить, если скопировать текст с браузера и потом вставить его в *Microsoft OneNote*, то он покажет источник(url страницы).